# PHP XML DOM: working with a subsection of an xml document

Tags: php, xml, dom

So I'm rather new to working with PHP's XML DOM. But I have trouble within the following problem. So imagine I have an xml document with several repeated sections, distinguishable by date. I'm trying to access a specific section by the date and then use tradition DOM methods to access data within that section. Here's what I'm currently doing.

XML document

```
<quizzes>
  <quiz>
    <date>Yesterday</date>
    <question>This is the day's question</question
  </quiz>
  <quiz>
    <date>Today</date>
    <question>This is the day's question</question
  </quiz>
  <quiz>
    <date>Tomorrow</date>
    <question>This is the day's question</question
  </quiz>
</quizzes
```

PHP Code

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument()
$xmlDoc->load($aboveXMLFile)

$subSection = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("quiz")->item(0)
$dateofSubSection = $subSection->getElementsByTagName("date")->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $dateofSubSection
```

I'm getting an error that says `getElementsbyTagName` is not a valid method for `$subSection`. Why?
And if I can't do this, how can select the subsection by date and then subsequently access nodeValues within that subsection alone?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "I 'm getting errors" is meaningless most of the time. Be more specific. All the way specific, to be exact.

Comment: $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument, replace it with $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

Comment: The function is `getElementsByTagName`, not `getElementsByName`, are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you give us the exact text of the error you are getting?

Comment: @Rohit Kumar Choudhary: That makes no difference at all.

Comment: Also please post your actual code, it's clear that the snippet you posted is not correct as it is full of syntax errors as well as contextual errors (i.e. `nodeValues` instead of `nodeValue`). Don't make us guess what might be wrong by showing code that you haven't even tried.

Comment: Ok -- well let me rephrase the whole question -- can getElementsbyTagName be a method of an of DOMNodeList? When I use getElementsbyTagName on the DOMDocument, this returns an instance of DOMNodeList, but can i use this method again on the newly generated DOMNodeList object? The manual does not list this as a method, so the answer is probably no.

Answer (score 2):

Check the spelling of the method.

it's `getElementsByTagName`

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php